# `'Observable<ModelEvent[]>': _isScalar, source, operator, lift, and 5 more.` - how to fix this error?

Tags: observable, angular7, ngrx-store, ngrx-effects

I am getting an error as :

`'Observable<ModelEvent[]>': _isScalar, source, operator, lift, and 5 more.` - But not able to fix it. I don't know the issue what it going on as well. any one help me?

here is my ts file :

```
import { Component, OnInit, ChangeDetectionStrategy, ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';
import { Store, select } from '@ngrx/store';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError, tap, map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import * as fromRoot from  "./../../state/";
import { CalendarActions, Load } from "./../../state/calendar.actions";
import { ModelEvent, EventState } from "./../../models/model.event";
declare var $:JQueryStatic;

@Component({
    selector: 'calendar-shell',
    templateUrl: './calendar-shell.component.html'
})
export class CalendarShellComponent implements OnInit {

    events$:Observable<ModelEvent[]>;
    currentEvent$:ModelEvent;

    constructor(private store:Store<fromRoot.NewState>) { }

    ngOnInit():void {

        this.store.dispatch(new Load());
        this.store.pipe(select(fromRoot.getEvents)).subscribe((events) => {
            this.events$ = events.map( (event) => {
                return {
                    title : event.title,
                    start : new Date(),
                    end : new Date(),
                    allDay : event.allDay,
                    id : event.id
                }
            })

        });

        const headerHeight          = $('.site-header').outerHeight();
        const footerHeight          = $('.site-footer').outerHeight();
        const siteRow               = $('.site-row');
        const leftSidebar           = $('#left-sidebar');
        const headerNavToggleBtn    = $('#headerNav-toggle-btn');
        const leftNaviToggleBtn     = $('#leftNavi-toggle-btn');
        //moving content down to header
        $('body').css({paddingTop: headerHeight});

        leftSidebar.hide();

        headerNavToggleBtn.on('click', function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            siteRow.addClass('sidenav-shows');
            leftSidebar.show();
            headerNavToggleBtn.hide();
        });

        leftNaviToggleBtn.on('click', function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            leftSidebar.hide();
            headerNavToggleBtn.show();
            siteRow.removeClass('sidenav-shows');
        });

    }

}
```

detailed error :

```
ERROR in src/app/calendar/containers/calendar-shell/calendar-shell.component.ts(25,4): error TS2740: Type '{ title: string; start: Date; end: Date; allDay: boolean; id: number; }[]' is missing the following properties from type 'Observable<ModelEvent[]>': _isScalar, source, operator, lift, and 5 more.
```

any one help me? if require any other details let me know.
Thanks in advance.